# Difference between the two types of ReadOnlyDictionary?

Tags: .net, dictionary

Does anyone know the difference between `System::Collections::ObjectModel::ReadOnlyDictionary` and `Microsoft::TeamFoundation::Client::ReadOnlyDictionary`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the [Team Foundation one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732967.aspx) was introduced simply because there wasn't a read-only dictionary in the main framework, and they wanted to expose one.

The [.NET framework one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875.aspx) was only introduced in .NET 4.5.

The .NET framework version is documented to just be a wrapper around an existing dictionary - so while it's read-only from a client point of view, it could still change over time. It's not clear (from the docs) whether the Team Foundation one behaves in the same way, although I'd expect it to (as the simplest approach).

Comment: @MiroBucko: That seems an unwarranted guess to me. I *suspect* that the two are very similar indeed - all they need to do is wrap a dictionary, after all.

Comment: @JonSkeet - `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary` implements `IReadOnlyDictionary`. Would this cause a change in the way they might behave?

Comment: @Shaks: No, it just means that in .NET 4.5 there's a bunch of read-only collection interfaces which weren't present before. It allows for generic covariance, but it's not really a chance in behaviour as such. What sort of change in behaviour were you expecting?